# Multiplying sum of selected rows within mutate function

Tags: r, dplyr

I would very much appreciate your help in using `mutate_at`.

I want to multiply a value by the sum of the corresponding row. The first column, however, contains the ID and should therefore be ignored. It should go in the following direction, but I can't get it right.

```
library("dplyr")

df <- data.frame(id = c(101,102,103,104),
                 t_1 = sample(0:100, 4)/100,
                 t_2 = sample(0:100, 4)/100,
                 t_3 = sample(0:100, 4)/100,
                 t_4 = sample(0:100, 4)/100)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("t_")),
                 funs(adjusted = 1/rowSums(select(., starts_with("t_")))*.))
```

Does anyone know any advice? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very effective solution but it works:

```
df %>%
  mutate(temp = rowSums(select(., grep("t_", names(df), value = TRUE)))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("t_")), funs(adjusted = 1/temp*.)) %>%
  select(-temp)

   id        t_1        t_2       t_3        t_4 t_1_adjusted t_2_adjusted t_3_adjusted t_4_adjusted
1 101 0.02822581 0.39919355 0.3185484 0.25403226   0.02822581   0.39919355    0.3185484   0.25403226
2 102 0.60273973 0.06849315 0.0000000 0.32876712   0.60273973   0.06849315    0.0000000   0.32876712
3 103 0.42285714 0.05142857 0.4400000 0.08571429   0.42285714   0.05142857    0.4400000   0.08571429
4 104 0.34934498 0.34061135 0.3100437 0.00000000   0.34934498   0.34061135    0.3100437   0.00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy, 
here is some solution without `mutate_at`:

```
nominator <- apply(df[,-1], 1, sum)
df[,-1] <- df[,-1]/nominator
```

This will first calculate the row sum as `nominator` and will divide each row entry of `df` (except the first entry) by the row nominator.